# Acceder a metodos de una clase inicializada desde otro proceso en NodeJS JavaScript

Tags: javascript, nodejs

tengo en mi fichero clase.js lo siguiente:

```
class MiClase{
    constructor(){}
    metodo1(){
        console.log("metodo1")
    }
}
const c = new MiClase();
```

Ejecuto el fichero mediante `node clase.js` y creo una instancia;

La cuestion es que me gustaría acceder desde otros ficheros a las propiedades y metodos de esa instancia y no crear nuevas instancias, de que forma se puede lograr eso en NodeJS?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Creo que no entiendes el ciclo de vida de los procesos o no terminas de entender lo que conlleva la comunicación entre procesos. Ese código crea una instancia e inmediatamente completa su ejecución... destruyendo la instancia

Comment: Suena a Dependency Injection? O tal vez un simple `import/require`? No me queda claro lo que preguntas. Puedes dar ejemplos?

Comment: Creo que no me expliqué bien, quisiera saber si puedo, al ejecutar el fichero clase.js y crear una instancia de MiClase, mantener esa instancia activa, por ejemplo si tuviera un contador, mantener los datos, y si en algun momento desde otro fichero requiero dicha clase pueda obtener los datos actuales del contador, y del mismo modo si desde otro fichero requiero la clase y ejecuto un metodo que sume al contador que el contador afectado sea el original creado desde el principio

Answer (score 0):

Claro que es posible utilizando el patrón Singleton.

Por ejemplo:

```
class Singleton{

    static _instancia;
    contador = 0;

    constructor(){
        if(  Singleton._instancia  ){
            return Singleton._instancia;
        }
        Singleton._instancia = this;
    }

    incremetar(){
        this.contador++;
    }

    getContador(){
        return this.contador;
    }

}


const instanciaClase1 = new Singleton();
instanciaClase1.incremetar();
instanciaClase1.getContador();
```

Espero te haya podido ayudar.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del mismo proceso, y de la manera como estás instanciando tu clase, tu código siempre usa la misma instancia, por lo que su unicidad es trivial. (se produce un singleton de facto)

Si tu aplicación generase procesos hijos via spawn o fork, tendría un canal de comunicación privilegiado con éstos, pero es un sistema de mensajes, no un acceso al estado interno del proceso hijo.

Si se trata de procesos independientes, la comunicación con otros procesos se limita a la interfaz que éstos expongan (ej: TCP/IP, unix sockets). Exponer el estado interno o permitir que otros procesos lo modifiquen es una falla de seguridad grave.  Imagínate que sólamente abriendo VSCode una extensión maliciosa pudiera examinar lo que se escribe al visitar mi banco en Chrome.

Esto sí ha ocurrido aunque con un alcance limitado, y fue lo que llevó a Ryan Dahl a crear Deno.